# Ошибка: "'GraphViz\'s executables not found'"

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть такой код, при запуске получаю ошибку:

> GraphViz\'s executables not found

На ноуте (MacOS) уже установлена Anaconda, я так понимаю, что проблема в том, что не установлен `GraphViz`.

Когда набираю в терминале:

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz=2.38.0
```

Получаю ошибку:

> invalid package specification: graphviz=2.38.

Как решить эту проблему?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
test_idx =[0, 50, 100]

#training data
train_target =np.delete(iris.target, test_idx)
train_data =np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis=0)

#testing data
test_target = iris.target[test_idx]
test_data = iris.data[test_idx]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_data, train_target)

print test_target
print clf.predict(test_data)

#viz code

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydot
dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf,out_file=dot_data,feature_names=iris.feature_names,
class_names=iris.target_names,filled=True, rounded=True, impurity=False)

graph =pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Comment: А зачем вы ясно версию graphviz указываете?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  Это хороший вопрос, попробовала: conda install -c anaconda graphviz,  без указания версии - помогло! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась с помощью того, что в команде:

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
```

Была убрана версия `graphviz`.